# How to capture network packet in Android without using any root permissions

Tags: android, capture, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

I want to capture network data packets on android app. Do you have any suggestions or source code to help me understand if this is possible?

Comment: I certainly hope that this is impossible, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: It is definitely possible, because Juniper network's VPN app uses it.

Answer (score 5):

Without root you will have to use a pass-thru method.

1. Setup your PC/Mac to share your wired connection through the
   wireless adapter
2. Connect to the wireless adapter with your Android device
3. Run wireshark

Comment: I want to capture network data packets on my android device by my app.Not pc only device.I want to list which sites users are connected on device. Thanks

Comment: And that's what I've just explained how to do.  Unless you have root, you can't trace packets.  Your only choice is what I've listed above which lets you sniff packets that your android device is sending out by sending traffic through the PC.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I have to super user.

Answer (score 0):

most apps that filter/sniff/account network traffic in android without root use the loopback vpn trick, where you setup a vpn and inspect the traffic (or whatever you want)

for sniffer, check [tpacketcapture](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.taosoftware.android.packetcapture), but i don't think you have the source... try to contact then, or check fdroid for a similar open source app

Answer (score 0):

This should be just man-in-the-middle approach - think about setting up a proxy.